# DOMPDF page breaking inside table

Tags: css, dompdf

I'm currently creating a form inside a php using DOMPDF. I have this problem when the table splits, the rows doesn't seem to close. (the bottom border of the table row).

What my page looks like:
[image]

But how can i make it to be like this?
[image]

Html code:

```
<div>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-title" colspan="3">ASSESSMENT</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-left">ASSESSMENT CRITERIA</th>
                    <th class="align-left">COMMENTS BY PRINCIPAL COORDINATING SUPERVISOR</th>
                    <th class="align-left">COMMENTS BY HEAD, GRADUATE STUDIES AND RESEARCH EDUCATION</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>1. How is the student's work being funded?</p>
                        (i.e., external, self, university, etc.)
                    </td>
                    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
                    <td>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>2. Has the student participated in conferences before?</p>
                        (i.g., Yes, CONF2014, self-funded)
                    </td>
                    <td>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</td>
                    <td>with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always f</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>3. Student's progress in the HDR program</p>
                        (i.e., whether progress has been satisfactory, as per annual review.)
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>4. Does the submission qualify for Higher Education Research Data Collection (HERDC)?</p>
                        (i.e., whether the submission was independently peer reviewed)
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>5. Potential for journal publications (or any other prestigious outcomes)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>6. What specific value will the conference add to the student's graduate studies?</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always f</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="criteria"><p>7. Will the student present his/her conference experience in a post grauduate seminar?</p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: The sample code you posted doesn't appear to produce the problem. Might have something to do with your styling. Can you post a more filled-out sample that includes both the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Did you found a solution? Because I have the same problem.